# HTML data-attributes in WebGrid rows

Tags: razor, asp.net-mvc-5, webgrid

I have a html `<table>` built on WebGrid and I would like to have an unique 'data-attribute' value to each row.

Is it possible to include to these 'rows' (`<tr>`), an "Id" or a custom value?

What i would like to have, is something like this:

```
<table>
    <tr data-id="customValue"></tr>
    <tr data-id="anyOtherName"></tr>
    <tr data-id="ThirdOptionValue"></tr>
</table>
```

But i don't know any option from WebGrid to have this kind of result.

One example of what i would like to have (but with WebGrid):

```
 @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr data-id="@item.Id">
                <td>...</td>     
            </tr>
        }
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Try adding some sample code so people can try and debug on that.

Comment: Please provide us with the code you are using so we can have a look at what you are trying to do.

Comment: I updated my question, trying to make it clearer